# Notepad++: delete all after fifth comma

Tags: notepad++

In nodepad++ I need to remove everything after the fifth comma in each line. But if there is less than five commas in some line, then nothing is deleted there. Example:

From

```
One,Two,Three,Four,Five,Six,Seven
One,Two,Three,Four,Five,Six,Seven,Eight
One
One,Two,Three
One,Two,Three,Four,Five,Six
```

To

```
One,Two,Three,Four,Five
One,Two,Three,Four,Five
One
One,Two,Three
One,Two,Three,Four,Five
```

I found here similar examples with two commas. But I can not adapt to my task.

Comment: Open in excel. Remove desired columns. Save as csv.

Comment: What do you mean? Open text file in Excel? I have opened it, but everything is in one column.

Comment: @Alines If you want to edit that in Excel, make sure to select *"Delimited"* as your original data type when you open it.

Comment: In excel, everything worked out for me. Thank you. Very convenient and reliable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try the following find and replace, in regex mode:

```
Find:    ^([^,]*(?:,[^,]*){4}).*$
Replace: $1
```

This regex pattern says to:

- `^` from the start of each line
- `(` start capturing in `$1`

  - `[^,]*` a single CSV term
  - `(?:,[^,]*){4}` followed by comma and another CSV term (so 5 in total)
- `)` stop capture
- `.*` match the remainder of the line
- `$` end of the line

Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Krrhv/2).

Comment: Amazing answer! I would have made a Python script to cleanup the file xD

Comment: @C-3PO Well nothing wrong with Python.  We could have used `re.findall` in this case.

Comment: It works for a simple example. But my file has 2200 lines and many have 40-50 data separated by commas. And for some reason there in some lines it leaves 1-2 commas instead of 5

Comment: @Alines I am guessing you have some empty values in there.  Check the edit to my answer.

Comment: Yes. Now everything works correctly. Thanks a lot.